# How to update a Javascript variable using a bash script?

Tags: javascript, bash

I need to update a javascript variable with a variable that is in a bash script. For example, in `variable.js`:

```
class Variables{}
Variables.name = '';
```

When a user runs the bash script, they will provide a name ex: `script.sh --name=Foo` and I want to update Variables.name to become 'Foo'.

I don't want the script to modify the `variable.js` file; I only want the variable to be changed when the program is running. Once the program is killed, the variable will become and empty string again.

How would I do this?

Comment: what is the runtime for script.sh and what for variable.js?

Comment: You can't change a variable inside a running program from `bash`.